# What does "then" mean in these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider:

> 1. Mary's not here. She'll be at a meeting downtown all afternoon. I guess I'll just have to wait until tomorrow and have her help me **then**.
> 2. A: Ms.Jones left right around 3.00.
>      B: I'll have to call her home, **then**. This report can't wait. We have to talk about it before tomorrow.
> 3. A: We're playing tennis this afternoon. Would you like to join us? 
>      B: Thanks, but I'm really wiped out. 
>      A: **Then** you'd better rest.

Does **then** in topic 1 and topic 2 have the same meaning?

Answer (score 4):

No, they're two different meanings.

1. Mary's not here. She'll be at a meeting downtown all afternoon. I guess I'll just have to wait until tomorrow and have her help me **at that time**.
2. A: Ms.Jones left right around 3.00. B: I'll have to call her home, **as a consequence**. This report can't wait. We have to talk about it before tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. In the topic 3, I think "then" means "as a consequence". Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* interpret topic 1 in a way such that they have the same meaning, but this is not the most likely meaning. Adding a comma before "then" could help support this alternate interpretation:

> I guess I'll just have to wait until tomorrow and have her help me, then.

This could make sense because the sentence discusses both a consequence *and* a time.

The most likely understanding of those sentences, and the two forms of "then", is given by @dan04's answer.